# Conflict between Tomcat8.5 and Jackson2

Tags: tomcat, jackson, tomcat8, jackson2, tomcat8.5

I am currently trying to call a google play developer api and to do so I need to use the Jackson2 library. Eclipse does not have any error messages when I build. However, when I deploy the war file, I can not start the web application. This happens when I add the following lines:

```
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory();
```

I also used jHades to verify that there are no overlapping jar files. Also, the import statements I used are for jackson2 are:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
```

These are the following war files I added to tomcat:

```
api-common-1.10.1.jar                                      google-oauth-client-1.31.1.jar
google-api-client-1.30.11.jar                              guava-30.0-android.jar
google-api-client-http-1.2.3-alpha.jar                     httpclient-4.5.13.jar
google-api-client-jackson2-1.30.11.jar                     httpcore-4.4.13.jar
google-api-client-json-1.2.3-alpha.jar                     j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
google-api-client-util-1.2.3-alpha.jar                     jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar
google-api-services-androidpublisher-v3-rev142-1.25.0.jar  jackson-core-2.12.0-rc1.jar
google-auth-library-credentials-0.22.0.jar                 jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar
google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.0.jar                 jsr305-3.0.2.jar
google-http-client-1.37.0.jar                              opencensus-api-0.24.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.37.0.jar                     opencensus-contrib-http-util-0.24.0.jar
json-20200518.jar
```

The error message I am receiving from tomcat is:

```
10-Nov-2020 13:09:20.018 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:781)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
10-Nov-2020 13:09:20.020 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using java version "1.8.0_261".

Thank you.

Comment: Don't mix different Jackson versions: you have `jackson-core` version `2.12.0-rc1`, while the remaining Jackson artifacts are version `2.11.3`.

Answer (score 0):

tomcat8.5 and higer version support jackson 2.10 and later.  tomcat8 should choose jackson 2.9

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).